# cant able to exchanges elements in array

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iPhone.what i did is creating an array with images as shown below

```
images = [NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjets:@"image1.jpg",@"image2.jpg",@"image3.jpg",@"image4.jpg",@"image5.jpg",@"image6.jpg",nil]
```

and i create a button when ever button click images are exchanged for that i am writing code as fallows in button clicked event.

```
[_images exchangeObjectAtIndex:2 withObjectAtIndex:4];
```

but images are not exchanged and i did n't get any warnings and images.i am writing array in viewDidLoad.what is the wrong.how can i exchange elements in the array. thank u in advance.

Comment: How do you change button image? Your array contains strings and it looks they should exchange ok - the problem must be in another place...

Comment: Yes its perfectly ok. your array is changed and you will have the sequence as `@"image1.jpg",@"image2.jpg",@"image5.jpg",@"image4.jpg",@"image3.jpg",@"image6.jpg"` in your array..

Comment: Hey MaheshBabu, just a request: Please put correct code in your questions. The code here is not correct the first line is missing an opening bracket '[' and in second line, the variable name '_images' is different from the name 'image' you created in first line. Although readers are smart enough to understand what you want to ask, its really irritating and hard to ignore these problems when looking at some code. I have seen you putting wrong code in some of your other questions too. You can try compiling the code before pasting it here.. I'm sorry if I've offended you in any way. As for the qu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting an array of images to then put into a UIImage so it goes through all the images one by one?

If so then when you change this array it will not change the order of the UIImages. You will need to change the array as you currently are then assign the array to the UIImage again like you would have done before. This would then show you the new and hopefully correct sequence of images.

I may be a bit wrong and you are using each location in the array to create a UIImage then put all those UIImages into a UIImageView. But what i am saying still applies, you would have to assign the new array to the UIImageView.